# use string with quots in configuration appsetting and regular expression to find pattern

Tags: c#, regex

use string with quots in  configuration appsetting separated by "|" and
find pattern from  input String using regular expression match keyword

```
<add key="SignatureWord" value="IN WITNESS|For this purpose|Please confirm your agreement|Acknowledged and Agreed|EXECUTED by the parties|(i) Any amount (the &quot;Early Termination Amount&quot;)"/>


public bool isSignature()
    {
NodeVal="(i) Any amount (the \"Early Termination Amount\") payable to one party  (the        \"Payee\")by the other party (the \"Payer\") under Section 6(e)";
        bool isSignature = false;

        string kWordforSignature = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SignatureWord"].ToString();

        Match mObj = Regex.Match(NodeVal, @"\b" + kWordforSignature + @"\b", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if ((mObj.Success) && (NodeVal.IndexOf(mObj.ToString().Trim()) == 0))
        {
            isSignature = true;
        }
        return isSignature;
    }
```

Not working in case of  keyword "(i) Any amount (the \"Early Termination Amount\")" define
in appsetting while all other keyword like "IN WITNESS" etc work properly

Comment: Its not very clear, what you exactly need, What is the out you are expecting ? What kind of pattern matching you want to perform. Please elaborate

Comment: I have a xml file of html tags and i read line by line and find akeyword that define in set of keyword in appsetting file seprated by "|" each line is check by matching keyword using regx . Problem is that if any word contain special character like "\"" not matched

Answer (score 2):

Parentheses are a special character used for group matching.  You need to escape them with a backslash in the regex.

Given that you do not use matching groups in any way, unescaped parentheses work as if they didn't occur in the regex at all which is why their occurrence in the input prevents a match.